# RGB Color Code for Stainless Steel

Tags: rgb

Is there a standard RGB color code for stainless steel?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Google suggests `stainless steel rgb(224, 223, 219)`.

Answer (score 0):

I use RGB 192,192,196 
for 3D shader surfaces.